# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user ''

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to run my entity framework model on the web.

Here is my connection string:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://*/EmployeeModel.csdl|res://*/EmployeeModel.ssdl|res://*/EmployeeModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=BTC-L8LBXTY1-2\MSSQLSRVER2014;initial catalog=Test;integrated security=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

I don't have a username or password to go with my connection string, but some other posts have said it could be one of those?

Here is the stack trace of errors that I receive:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user ''.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +821
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +332
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +699
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +89
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +426
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +191
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +154
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +21
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +209
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure) +41

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +967
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +22
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +9
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +114
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +883
```

[image: This is my database connection.]

I added the parameters to my connection string for the username matching this one, and an empty password.

Comment: Summary: `Login failed for user ''`

Comment: You do need a username/password.

Comment: How do I determine which username/password I need? Is it the details for my computer's account, or something else?

Comment: `integrated security=False` means that you will provide credentials, True means that it will use user under which application is running. I think you should switch it to True

Comment: I have tried it using integrated security True as well but I got the same result, so I guess I don't have to use my account credentials

Comment: "trying to run my entity framework model on the web" - so where is your (web) database?

Comment: My database is in SQL Server

Comment: That is not a location.

Comment: Do you mean the file location? I am new to this I am not sure what you are asking

Comment: I am just following this tutorial in order to learn the entity framework http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2014/05/part-1-what-is-entity-framework.html

Comment: You would have to put your username and  password in the connection string. These are the same credentials you use for connecting to your database in sql server. You can create a user for your database in sql server.

Comment: Ok I'll look into how to do that, thanks

Comment: But first you need a SQL server that you can reach from your Webserver. It's not clear if you have that set up.

Comment: How do I know if it's set up? I tested the connection earlier when I created the ADO.NET Entity Framework Data Model and it said Test Connection Successful

Comment: @bommelding I updated the bottom of my post, is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @MarkHollis To make a new account, login using windows authentication in SQL Server Management Studio, then right click on the "Security" folder under your database and select "New > Login".  Make sure to check the radio button for "SQL server authentication" and not windows auth.

Comment: I am not sure if my work will allow this... do I need to make another account? Why can't I connect to the current one?

Comment: If you want to test on LocalHost or intranet that should be fine. But your question starts with "on the web".  If that is the case you should make a plan and review it with your Db, Network and security managers.

Comment: No that's my mistake, just localhost is all I wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you can put integrated security=true to login with windows credentials or add your username and password in the connectionstring, Just add a user and add the details